# How to develop with libGDX on both Android and Desktop (IntelliJ 2018 CE /Gradle) with Java 8

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, java-8, libgdx

Slowly learning gradle. *It is essential (to me) to rule out IDE bugs and run my project from the command line. This lead me to discover my path was referring to a JRE instead of JDK; I got an error message stating that tools.jar was not on the path and that was that.*

*However I still cannot get past about 80-something percent when I execute `gradlew desktop:debug`.*

Hence this question is concerned with IntelliJ that I recently upgraded to the 2018 version. Version 2017 was working fine, with a big disclaimer that I wasn't, in fact using Java8 lambda's at that time. Moving to 2018 I felt it easier to create a new libGDX (best way I know to target multiple platforms) project to dump all my files into rather than debug all the (often unhelpful) stack traces I was getting.

Out of the box I performed minimal further modifications to gradle to get the desktop version working. I really don't want to repeat that as I opt for a new name which means a lot of editing and breaking. When it came to deploying on Android I got stuck.

What are the modifications needed to Gradle versions and gradle files to get Android builds working? For bonus points, why are there apparently 4 different versions of gradle involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent a lot of time to make libgdx compile in java8. And I did it. Works to me and my friends. If you wish to try it and it fails right away, give Intellij a couple of restarts and cache invalidations. Might need to delete .gradle from %userdir% (not necessarily), but in the end it worked stable.

Here is my config:

Intellij IDEA 18+ or Android studio 3.0+

wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5-bin.zip
```

Project build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    google() //add google repo
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' //higher versions were not compiling right
}
```

Andoird build.gradle:

```
android{
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16 //16 is good enough for 2018
        targetSdkVersion 27
        //Forget about Jack if you were using it. 
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}
eclipse { 

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}
```

and for the Desktop build.gradle

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

Comment: @John. Hah, it's not that clean. I just written changes over default libgdx gradle configuration. Don't delete anything else

Comment: wow, thanks for all the effort that went into discovering this stuff. One thing I noticed, I needed to add `jcenter()` next to `google()`, not sure how I decided that amongst the various other repo's, but I was missing something to do with kotlin (possibly legacy from my previous intention to write this in kotlin) until I did. I didn't even have to delete any .gradle file/folder.

Answer (score 3):

In my top level build.gradle, by default I had

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
...
```

which I had to change to

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    }
...
```

and extend:

```
buildscript {
...
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
```

Next, Lint and other sources led me to change a line of gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties from

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`

to

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

To my android level build.gradle add either:

```
android {
...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
...
```

or

```
android {
...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
...
```

I'm posting this answer not because it's elegant or particularly enlightening but merely because it is the easiest way I know to switch my development between Android and desktop (it works in reverse). The error's I'm getting from IntelliJ and gradle were far from helpful and took a lot of research which is distilled here.

**Update**

I got stuck going back to Desktop and was getting a massive untraceable dump that I want to include for future reference:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$configureProject$1(BasePlugin.java:436)
...
```

What that meant is that I hadn't followed the instructions I had confused the configurations described above.

Comment: While this was a quick and repeatable solution, wilder modifications to these files as described by maklas below have got libgdx working with java8, which I think was the issue as when I was using IntelliJ 2017 I wasn't using 8's lambdas.